# Why HTTPD open too many files?

Tags: mysql, apache, io

I have tried to show how many files are open via this command:

lsof | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | uniq -c | sort -n -r

and here is result:

```
 717 mysqld 1762
    188 httpd 5171
    185 httpd 5145
    184 httpd 5631
    184 httpd 5488
    184 httpd 5150
    184 httpd 3824
    184 httpd 3819
    184 httpd 3811
    184 httpd 3483
    184 httpd 3255
    184 httpd 3249
    184 httpd 3236
    184 httpd 3230
    183 httpd 5655
    183 httpd 5490
    183 httpd 5489
    183 httpd 5487
    183 httpd 5465
    183 httpd 5464
    183 httpd 5149
    183 httpd 4480
    183 httpd 4479
    183 httpd 4478
    183 httpd 4477
    183 httpd 4474
    183 httpd 4473
    183 httpd 4459
    183 httpd 3490
    183 httpd 3489
    183 httpd 3488
    183 httpd 3487
    183 httpd 3484
    183 httpd 3478
    183 httpd 3326
    183 httpd 3235
    183 httpd 3234
    183 httpd 3233
    183 httpd 3231
    183 httpd 3229
    183 httpd 10551
    183 httpd 10317
    183 httpd 10316
    183 httpd 10291
    182 httpd 10602
    182 httpd 10601
    182 httpd 10281
    174 httpd 5443
    174 httpd 3319
    174 httpd 10603
    174 httpd 10596
    174 httpd 10578
    174 httpd 10577
    174 httpd 10552
    174 httpd 10531
    173 httpd 10576
    173 httpd 10378
    173 httpd 10319
    173 httpd 10318
    171 httpd 3226
    137 master 1985
    118 dovecot 1854
     74 newrelic- 1880
     63 sshd 8631
     62 auth 11282
     57 fail2ban- 2107
     56 auth 11283
     49 qmgr 2007
     49 pickup 31235
     44 squid 2061
     44 memcached 1002
     41 sshd 1183
     37 squid 2059
     34 log 1857
     27 vsftpd 1206
     27 imap 7971
     24 anvil 1855
     22 config 11280
     20 rsyslogd 869
     20 init 1
     19 udevd 363
     19 crond 2042
     15 unlinkd 2063
     15 udevd 911
     15 udevd 910
     15 mysqld_sa 1246
     15 lsof 11502
     15 bash 8687
     13 acpid 895
     12 sort 11505
     12 awk 11503
     10 newrelic- 1879
     10 lsof 11506
     10 irqbalanc 884
      9 uniq 11504
      8 mingetty 2155
      3 xenwatch 23
      3 xenbus 24
      3 sync_supe 56
      3 netns 19
      3 migration 9
      3 migration 7
      3 migration 5
      3 migration 4
      3 kthreadd 2
      3 kswapd0 117
      3 kstriped 292
      3 ksoftirqd 8
      3 ksoftirqd 6
      3 ksoftirqd 3
      3 ksoftirqd 10
      3 ksnapd 296
      3 kseriod 68
      3 kjournald 318
      3 khvcd 136
      3 khelper 16
      3 kblockd/3 63
      3 kblockd/2 62
      3 kblockd/1 61
      3 kblockd/0 60
      3 kauditd 570
      3 flush-202 725
      3 events/3 14
      3 events/2 13
      3 events/1 12
      3 events/0 11
      3 crypto/3 125
      3 crypto/2 124
      3 crypto/1 123
      3 crypto/0 122
      3 cpuset 15
      3 bdi-defau 58
      3 async/mgr 20
      3 aio/3 121
      3 aio/2 120
      3 aio/1 119
      3 aio/0 118
      1 COMMAND PID
```

Folks, could you please tell me why Apache open so many files? I have disabled access_log directive at httpd.conf but it not helps me.

Thx

Comment: It opens as many files as it's needed to work. Any *real* problems with that?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the actual results (`lsof|grep httpd`), you will see that each parent process has open handles to each module that is loaded, so your modules (e.g. mod_rewrite) will be in the open file list.

Each process will also have a handle to the `error_log` file, lib files required to run httpd or any modules, and at least one pipe per process for IPC.

If you are serving a lot of static files and you have a busy site, chances are you will see some of those files open too.

Really none of this should be much of an issue.  And keep in mind, the more Server processes you have running, the more open files there will be since each parent process will open many of the same files (in particular the modules and log files).